# WooCommerce Show price next to product variation

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

I have a list of variations of a product but I would like to show the price next to it. This way the user can immediately see the price difference between each variations. http://cl.ly/15150P3D1U3k

Any way how to do this in WooCommerce knowing my site is multi-langual?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. Which i have just tested in the latest WordPress and WooCommerce. Just add it to your functions file.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', 'display_price_in_variation_option_name' );

function display_price_in_variation_option_name( $term ) {
    global $wpdb, $product;

    if ( empty( $term ) ) return $term;
    if ( empty( $product->id ) ) return $term;

    $result = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT slug FROM {$wpdb->prefix}terms WHERE name = '$term'" );

    $term_slug = ( !empty( $result ) ) ? $result[0] : $term;

    $query = "SELECT postmeta.post_id AS product_id
                FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS postmeta
                    LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS products ON ( products.ID = postmeta.post_id )
                WHERE postmeta.meta_key LIKE 'attribute_%'
                    AND postmeta.meta_value = '$term_slug'
                    AND products.post_parent = $product->id";

    $variation_id = $wpdb->get_col( $query );

    $parent = wp_get_post_parent_id( $variation_id[0] );

    if ( $parent > 0 ) {
         $_product = new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_id[0] );
         return $term . ' (' . wp_kses( woocommerce_price( $_product->get_price() ), array() ) . ')';
    }
    return $term;

}
```

Comment: That works indeed for most of the cases although in another language it sometimes says 'Undefined offset: 0' on $parent = wp_get_post_parent_id( $variation_id[0] ); ... Any idea? (See first three options at: http://luxsel.be/fr/product/sel-de-la-mer-morte-psotramil/)

Comment: Now you should be able to see it

Comment: Doesn't work with Woocommerce 3.x. All prices become the last variation price.

Comment: A couple of comments, incorrectly posted as answers, just popped in mentioning that this code generates errors in the latest version of WooCommerce. Error (snippet): `id was called incorrectly. Product properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'), ` ... `display_price_in_variation_option_name, WC_Abstract_Legacy_Product->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was added in version 3.0.`.